# What is the best way to parent armour to a game rig

Tags: rigging, game-engine, rigify

I have a rigify rig with armor parented to bones on layer 29 and the body weight painted to the rig but the game rig does not have the armor connected to it, how should i solve this? Should i just join all my items together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not, the only reliable way to bind anything to bones is weight groups. So re-parent that armor with armature deform and weights groups.

Unless the engine specifically requires it, there is no need to join objects together.